# EF Core 2 Migrate method doesn't create tables in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I have `.netcore 2.0` app with `N-Tier Architecture`, I have implemented `ApplicationDbContext` in `Data Access Layer`... Now I'm trying to Add new `Entities`, for example I have created entity `Test2`:

```
namespace MyProject.Domain
{
    public class Test2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I added `DbSet` in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Implementation.MySql.Contexts
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApplicationDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
                _configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql"));
        }

        public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Test2> Test2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I have called `.Migrate()` method in `BaseEnfine.cs`:

```
namespace MyProject.Infrastructure.Implementation.MySql
{
    public class BaseEngine : IBaseEngine
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        protected ApplicationDbContext Db => _context;

        protected BaseEngine(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (!_context.Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                _context.Database.Migrate();
                _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I refresh DB there's no table `Test2`..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first add migrations before migrating your DB.
There are 2 ways:

1. Using Package manager console:

   `Add-Migration InitialMigration`
2. With `dotnet` CLI:

   Add following code to your .csproj file:

   `<ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
        Version="2.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>`

   `cd` to your project directory with command line and run

   run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration`

In most cases it is better to not apply migrations in your app. You can use CLI to migrate database or generate scripts for migrations.

```
dotnet ef database update
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Read more about `dotnet ef` on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Make sure `dotnet` is added to the PATH.

Comment: I'm getting No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" error when I run "dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration"

Comment: @Arkadi Several conditions should be met to run this command:
1. You should run it from command line.
2. `dotnet` should be added to the PATH.
3. You should change directory to your current project's one.

Comment: @Arkadi, I've forgot about required NuGet package. Edited my post.

Comment: dotnet command exists in path but the problem is when I try to add nuget package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" to infrastructure (class library project) it fails to install

Comment: @Arkadi, Try to add to your .csproj file:

  `<ItemGroup>

    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>`

It should work

Comment: Added and now I'm getting "Version for package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet` could not be resolved." error when I run "dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165042/discussion-between-andrey-alonzov-and-arkadi).

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and solved as follow. I was using entityframeworkcore.
at first run this command from Package Manager Console

```
Update-Database -Migration 0
```

Then remove all migrations using this command

```
Remove-Migration
```

Then Create migration as like

```
Add-Migration initial_migration
```

Finally run update Command

```
Update-Database
```